# Out of memory while showing simple text in gridview in android

Tags: android, memory, gridview, out-of-memory

I am trying to show a gridview with text in it , basically it will be showing 7-8 values against every day of the year . so yes it gets pretty large pretty quickly.

And when i try to scroll down and i am in the middle , it runs out of memory.
here is how i am trying to do it

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        dateView = new TextView(mContext);
        dateView.setText(dateArray.get(position));
        dateView.setSingleLine(true);
        // dateview.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(70, 70));
        Log.d("--in get view--", "");
                return dateView;
}
```

Is there any better way to do it , like may be releasing the view which are not showing in the screen at the moment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should reuse views. Now you create new instance of `TextView` every time `getView` called. But you're given `convertView`. Android caches all views for you and reuse them, so instead of having 1000 views for every row it uses about 10-20 (how many visible on screen) views and reuse them. You should check first if `convertView` is not null then cast it to `TextView` and populate with your text otherwise you need to create `TextView` manually as you're doing now and return it. Check this tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html 5.2 ConvertView.

Comment: thanks , this is why i must read before i start coding , thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

It is creating new dateView every row display, (move up or down). Use layout inflate. To use it create an adapter layout, ad catch it in getview.

```
public static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView textView;       
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;
        try {

            if (convertView == null) {
                vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourTextviewInIt, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.textView = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView);                
                vi.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
            }

            holder.textView.setText(dateArray.get(position));
            holder.textView.setSingleLine(true);

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        return vi;
    }
```